# Sliding motion detection

Tags: iphone, ios

How could I detect a sliding motion of the phone? By "sliding" I mean some sort of lateral translation without a lot of shaking. I tried some stuff with the accelerometer but couldn't really get readings that would seem to be very helpful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out the section titled

#### Listing 4-6  Getting the instantaneous portion of movement from accelerometer data

from [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) on ways to extract more useful data from the raw accelerometer data:

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out and see if I can find something